# Bookmarks under List of Figures

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I want to automatically generate bookmarks under List of Figures. The code below adds bookmark for each Figure (which is good), but I fail to also automatically generate the same bookmarks under List of Figures (without manually entering the code commented out in the code below). Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
        linkcolor=blue,
        linktoc=page}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft} 

%%% Generate bookmarks for all figures
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\endfigure{%
\bookmark[
rellevel=1,
keeplevel,
dest=\@currentHref,
 ]{Figure \thefigure: \@currentlabelname}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\endfigure failed}}
\makeatother


% %%% Format list of tables and list of figures
\newlength{\mylen}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\space}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\space}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}


\begin{document}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
%\bookmark[
%    dest=Figure1,
%    rellevel=1,
%    keeplevel]{Figure 1: Figure caption text}
%\bookmark[
%    dest=Figure2,
%    rellevel=1,
%    keeplevel]{Figure 2: Figure caption text 2}
\newpage

\section{The document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text}
%\hypertarget{Figure1}{}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text 2}
%\hypertarget{Figure2}{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Current:
[image: Bookmarks in current document]

Goal:
[image: Ideal placement of bookmarks]

Comment: The problem is, that you want to add bookmarks from all over the document to something (LOF) right at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a related question here: [Custom bookmark list of figures and tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331579/custom-bookmark-list-of-figures-and-tables)

The easiest way is to write the same bookmark entry to the `.lof` file such that a bookmark is generated when `\listoffigures` is issued (by reading in the `.lof` file).

This can be achieved by using `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect{\bookmark{}...}` (see code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft} 

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
        linkcolor=blue,
        linktoc=page}
\usepackage{bookmark}

%%% Generate bookmarks for all figures
\makeatletter

\pretocmd\endfigure{%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect{%
    \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
    ]{Figure \thefigure: \@currentlabelname}}}%
\bookmark[
rellevel=1,
keeplevel,
dest=\@currentHref,
]{Figure \thefigure: \@currentlabelname}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\endfigure failed}}
\makeatother



% %%% Format list of tables and list of figures
\newlength{\mylen}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\space}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\space}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}


\begin{document}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{The document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{Different section}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]