# Custom bookmark list of figures and tables

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

I need a custom order bookmark for a document report:
currently, I'm using a macro from [Bookmarks under List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211473/bookmarks-under-list-of-figures)

I need a custom bookmark like this:

- List of contents

  - chapter 1 .......
  - chapter 2 ......
  - chapter 3 .....
- List of figures

  - Figure 1.1.......
  - Figure 2.4..........
- List of tables

  - Table 2.5 ........
  - Table 2.7 ......

Answer (score 4):

The linked post (which has an answer by me too) is not a solution to the problem, but it can be used as a starter.

The main problem is that a `\bookmark` command will enter the relevant information at the current level of the bookmark tree, this means the figure bookmarks will appear right between a `chapter` or `section` bookmark, but are not ordered or form a tree of themselves.

This can be cured by postponing the bookmark operation to some other place and faking some list of `figure bookmark` etc, which is doing the right bookmark entries at the end if `\listoffiguresbookmarks` is called at the end. (The same is true for `\listoftablesbookmarks`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
  linkcolor=blue,
  linktoc=page}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoffiguresbookmarks}{%
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{listoffiguresbookmark}
  \bookmarksetup{level=1}
  \@starttoc{lofb}
}
\newcommand{\listoftablesbookmarks}{%
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{listoftablesbookmark}
  \bookmarksetup{level=1}
  \@starttoc{lotb}
}

\makeatother

%%% Generate bookmarks for all figures and tables
\makeatletter

\pretocmd\endfigure{%
\addtocontents{lofb}{%
  \protect{%
    \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
    ]{Figure \thefigure: \@currentlabelname}}}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\endfigure failed}}
\pretocmd\endtable{%
\addtocontents{lotb}{%
  \protect{%
    \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
    ]{Table \thetable: \@currentlabelname}}}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\endtable failed}}

\makeatother



\AtEndDocument{%
  \listoffiguresbookmarks
  \listoftablesbookmarks
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{The document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{Different section}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text 2}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Table caption No. 1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that an improved version should check whether there's a caption at all

Comment: Instead of hacking the environment, you should redefine the command `\contentsline` while reading the lof file.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I am pretty sure, if I would have used a redefinition of `\contentsline`, the next complainer would have been there (And we have a lot of complainers here ;-) There are a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: Indeed :-) Next time I will redefine `\caption` :-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Not redefine, but patching. Actually, that's what I had in mind first, but I took the answer to the linked post and changed it slightly.

Answer (score 3):

Here another approach. You can modify it for your needs. The examples uses two captions inside a single figure environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,linktoc=page}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered, open, color=blue}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
 \begingroup
    \let\SAVEDcontentsline\contentsline
    \def\contentsline##1##2##3##4{%
       \SAVEDcontentsline{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}%
       \begingroup
         \def\numberline####1####2{####1:~####2}
         \bookmark[rellevel=1,keeplevel,dest=##4,]{\figurename~##2}%
       \endgroup  
     }%  
    \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}%
  \endgroup  
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\section{The document}
\subsection{the fist subsection}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption{Figure caption text 1}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\rule{6cm}{3cm}
\caption[Short form figrue 2]{long long long long long long long long long Figure caption text 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
      \subcaptionbox{A cat\label{cat}}
        {\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
      \subcaptionbox{An elephant\label{elephant}}
        {\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
      \caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}

\section{The second section}
\subsection{the second subsection}


\end{document}
```

[image]