# How to Edit the bookmark menu and add list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

According with my University standards the bookmark menu should look like the following figure:

[image: bookmark menu expected]

Currently my bookmark menu looks like the following:

[image: bookmark menu actual]

In case that its needed, my tex code is in [GitHub](https://github.com/figuedmundo/ubikate-documentation/blob/master/main.tex)

**Edit:**
Thanks for the welcome, as you suggest I'm adding code that can be compiled, indeed is my complete preamble and some mockup in order to see something in the bookmarks.

I tried the following solution: [Custom bookmark list of figures and tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331579/custom-bookmark-list-of-figures-and-tables), but I couldn't make it looks like as the requirement, please any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

%bookmarks
\usepackage{refcount}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\pdfcompresslevel=9

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\setsvg{
    svgpath = images/,
    inkscape = inkscape -z -D % conversion options for svg package, export drawing instead of page
}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
            citecolor=black,%
            filecolor=black,%
            linkcolor=black,%
            urlcolor=black}

%----------------------------------------
% Anexos
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}

\addto\captionsspanish{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
}

%------------
% Bibliografia
\addto\captionsspanish{
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografía}
}

%------------
%margenes
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, inner=3.5cm, outer=2.5cm]{geometry}

%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}% Clear page header/footer
\fancyfoot{}% Clear page header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%------------
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}
%----------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=C++
}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
%-------------
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}}
\pagenumbering{Roman} % para comenzar la numeracion de paginas en numeros romanos

\title{Desarrollo de una aplicaci\'on..}
\author{Edmundo Figueroa Herbas}
\date{\today \ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%para poner bookmark del CD de requisitos
\bookmark[page=1,level=-2]{INICIO}

% \include{dedicatoria}
\chapter*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedicatoria}
\begin{flushright}
  \textit{Para mi Familia.}\\
\end{flushright}

% \include{agradecimientos}
\chapter*{Agradecimientos} %
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Agradecimientos} %
\markboth{AGRADECIMIENTOS}{AGRADECIMIENTOS} %
¡Muchas gracias a todos!

% \include{resumen}
\chapter*{Resumen} %
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumen} %
\markboth{RESUMEN}{RESUMEN} %
Una bonita historia

\frontmatter
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables

\newpage
\mainmatter

  \chapter{Introducción} % (fold)
  \section{Antecedentes} % (fold)
  El presente proyecto consiste en
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{Diagrama Árbol de Problemas}
    \label{fig:arbolProblemas}
  \end{figure}
  \section{Descripción} % (fold)

  %
  \chapter{Campus Universitario}
  \section{Introducción}
  La Universidad Mayor de San Simón..
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{Mapa universitario}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{table}[H]
  \caption{Historias de Usuario}
  \end{table}


  \chapter{Implementación del Proyecto}
  \section{Planificación de la Entrega}
  \subsection{Plan de Entregas}
  \begin{table}[H]
      \begin{tabular}{ c  c  c }
        \toprule
          \textbf{Iteración} &
          \textbf{Historia de Usuario} &
          \textbf{Estimación [dias]}\\
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Estimación de la implementación.}
  \end{table}


  \appendix
  \clearpage
  \addappheadtotoc
  \appendixpage
  \begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Manual Instalación}
    El Manual de instalación..
    \section{Instalación de la base de datos}
    \chapter{Manual Usuario}
      \section{Página de Inicio}
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \caption{Página de Inicio.}
      \end{figure}


Es la primera vista,
  \end{appendices}

\backmatter{}
  % \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  % \bibliography{bibliografia}
  \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{xp_site} http://www.extremeprogramming.org/
  \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example demonstrating the issue i.e. code we can compile. Right now, it is not at all clear what you are asking. Is the point that your menu doesn't list the figures or tables/ How are you getting the bookmarks you do have? Do your lists of figures and tables appear in the document table of contents? Do you need them there as well? Etc. In any case, this is essentially unanswerable right now except with 'it depends on your existing code i.e. class, packages and configuration'.

Comment: This bookmark layout is completely different to what the default layout is when created via LaTeX. It'll take a lot of work to make things work this way.

Comment: @cfr as you suggested, I added code that can be compiled

Comment: It will not help that you are loading `hyperref` much too early. It likes being loaded late. Also, great to have some code, but it would be better if you could make it a bit more minimal by removing stuff which isn't relevant. I don't have an `images` sub-directory, for example, and I can't imagine I need to convert images to see your bookmarks, so take the irrelevant stuff out. (Leave stuff to do with cross-refs, references, links, ToC, LoT, LoF, document parts (appendix etc.) - anything that might be bookmarked - and headers/footers.)