# How put bookmark to figures and tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

how put bookmark to figures and tables?

the result of my code is:
[image]

i need the next result, 
it has to be divided by type, bookmark to chapters, bookmark for figures, bookmark for tables

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
    \makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Dedicatory}
       to all my family
    \chapter*{Abstract}
       hello world
    \chapter{chapter}
    \section{Introduction}
    In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be 
    used which are important and deserve to appear in

   \begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Table caption text]{This is a table with a very long caption text
 and it would be nice to use the short caption in the bookmark}
 \label{table 1}
\end{table}



    Index\index{Index}.
     \subsection{subsection}
    Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} 
    will also show up. Terms in the index can also be 
    nested \index{Index!nested}

    \clearpage

    \section{Second section}
    This second section\index{section} may include some special 

    \begin{figure}[ht]
     \centering
     \rule{6cm}{3cm}
     \caption{Figure caption text}
     \label{figura 1}
    \end{figure}
    word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

    \printindex
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Ass a label to your figures and tables (*after* the caption).

Comment: @Bernard i edited my question, see please

Answer (score 3):

With the help of `\hypertarget` and `\pdfbookmark` you gan achieve this result as demonstrated in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
    \makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Dedicatory}
       to all my family
    \chapter*{Abstract}
       hello world
    \chapter{chapter}
    \section{Introduction}
    In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be 
    used which are important and deserve to appear in

   \begin{table}[ht]
\hypertarget{table}{}
\addtocounter{table}{1}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Table \thetable: Table caption text}{mytable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Table caption text]{This is a table with a very long caption text
 and it would be nice to use the short caption in the bookmark}
 \label{mytable}

\end{table}


 the 
    Index\index{Index}.
     \subsection{subsection}
    Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} 
    will also show up. Terms in the index can also be 
    nested \index{Index!nested}

    \clearpage

    \section{Second section}
    This second section\index{section} may include some special 

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \hypertarget{figure}{}
    \addtocounter{figure}{1}
    \pdfbookmark[2]{Figure \thefigure: Figure caption text}{myfigure}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}
     \centering
     \rule{6cm}{3cm}
     \caption{Figure caption text}
     \label{myfigure}
    \end{figure}
    word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

    \printindex
    \end{document}
```

Comment: thanks but i edited my question with example, see please

Comment: Please see, if this answer can help you regarding the requirements you added in your edit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354616/134144