# Automatic creation and adapation of bookmark levels for figures and tables in PDF

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I need to write reports that not only need bookmarks for content structuring (sections, subsections, etc.), but also consider those for tables and figures. See expected result here:[image]

Note that in the example picture shown above, bookmarks for Tab. 1 and Fig. 1 have been created manually in Adobe Acrobat to illustrate the expected outcome.

Now, if the level of section changes, e.g., section 3.1 becomes section 3.1.1, the bookmark for Tab. 1 and Fig. 1 should also be placed one level lower. Is there a way, first, to create the table/figure bookmark by LaTeX itself, second, to achieve that kind of automatic adapation of bookmark level for tables and figures if the section level moves up or down? Also, a figure's bookmark should always match the short caption.

Here is the LaTeX code that I have used so far:

```
\documentclass[abstract=false]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{draftfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
        pdfstartview={XYZ null null 0.0}, 
        pdfview={XYZ 0 0 0},
        colorlinks=true,
        breaklinks=true,
        bookmarks=true,
        bookmarksopen=false,
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        linktocpage=true,
        backref=false,
        hyperfootnotes=false,
        hypertexnames=false,
} 

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TITLE PAGE}

\clearpage


% Table of contents, List of figures, List of tables --------------

\phantomsection % needed for hyperref
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\contentsname}  
   \tableofcontents
  \newpage
\phantomsection %needed for hyperref
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
 \listoftables
\phantomsection %needed for hyperref
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
 \listoffigures

\clearpage

% Main body-----------------------------------------------------

\section{Introduction}

\Blindtext[1]

\section{Objectives}

\Blindtext[2]

\section{Results}

\subsection{Subresults}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
     \centering
     \setkeys{draftfigure}{content={white box}} 
     \caption{A test image}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \caption{How to format columns}
  \label{tab:fmt}
  \centering                
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}l}
    \hline\hline
  Character & Description\\
    \hline                      
    \texttt{c}& Centered Column\\
    \texttt{l}& Left Column\\
    \texttt{r}& Right Column\\
    \texttt{@{\quad}}& Add Space\\
    \texttt{\small|}& {\small vertical line}\\
    \hline\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I found questions/answers regarding table/figure bookmarking here:  [How put bookmark to figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476662/how-put-bookmark-to-figures-and-tables) and here: [Custom bookmark list of figures and tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331579/custom-bookmark-list-of-figures-and-tables/354616#354616). These do not seem to work/apply.

Anyone volunteering to kindly provide solution for this?

Comment: make your example shorter and more concise.  Various code lines (e.g. all these colors) are quite irrelevant. Ensure that your example compiles on other computers by not using local figures.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried to condense the LaTeX code and included 'draftfigure' package in order not to use local images.